# Scope of event Listeners inside loop

Tags: javascript, scope, addeventlistener

How is the eventListener working inside **forLoop**?

The code works in the example.

When I toggle on either paragraph it turns a lower opacity and has a strike through.
When I hover on either paragraph they turn blue.

I want to understand how this is achieved **inside a for loop** after the browser loads the page. I'm just trying to understand how the browser interprets this code.

```js
var someTag = document.querySelectorAll("p")

for (var i = 0; i < someTag.length; i++) {


  someTag[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.classList.add("someClass");
  });
  someTag[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    this.classList.remove("someClass");
  });

  someTag[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
  })


}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.someClass {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: Is this code working? Can you share a fiddle? As far as I think  i will be one greater than the value of someTag's length after the loop finishes and it may not be working. Will be clearer if you can share a fiddle

Comment: What do you mean? The code seems to work. Do you mean that you want to know _how_ and _why_ it works, or does it not work and you are asking for an explanation? Or does it work in a way you do not expect? Although the explanation for that will most likely fall within one of the former explanations. Basically, can you be more specific what you need help with.

Comment: @Vatsal Thanks I just added the jsfiddle. I don't understand how the browser is running the loop more than once. Sorry any confusion.

Comment: How and why it works. I want an explanation too.
It seems like the browser will only load the code once, allow me to hover and click but then stop.

Comment: It seems like you don't understand the basic idea of an event listener. It's a function you attach to an element, and it will be executed every time the event happens to the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an event listener to an element, that's a permanent change to that element (unless you later remove it with `removeEventListener()`). The listener function will be called automatically by the browser whenever the event is triggered on the element. You only need to add the listener once, it will then react to all future occurrences of the event.

The other thing you need to know is that within the listener function, `this` will be a reference to the element that the event was triggered on. That's how your functions are able to change the class of the paragraph you click or hover on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barmar! I didn't know that a function can be a permanent change to an element

Answer (score 0):

First off this code is working only because you are appending the value to this and this in this case is the value you are hovering over. 
When you hover over p tag the code is working only because this is set to the current **p** tag you are hovering on. It has nothing to do with the value of i.

See the fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/w1ao28d2/

Variables in javascript are function scoped which means the value of i is still available even when you are out of the loop. So when you hover over the p tag the value of i is 2 which is undefined. Please check the fiddle console logs.

```
var someTag = document.querySelectorAll("p")

//ES5
for (var i = 0; i < someTag.length; i++) {


  someTag[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
console.log(this);
if(i == 0){
    this.classList.add("someClass0");
}else if(i == 1){
    this.classList.add("someClass1");
}else{
    console.groupCollapsed(' See Information regarding variable values for mouseover');
    console.log(someTag[i]);
  console.log(i);
    console.log(this);
  console.groupEnd();
    this.classList.add("someClass2");
}

});
someTag[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
 if(i == 0){
    this.classList.remove("someClass0");
}else if(i == 1){
     this.classList.remove("someClass1");
}else{
  console.groupCollapsed(' See Information regarding variable values for mouseout');
    console.log(someTag[i]);
    console.log(i);
    console.log(this);
    console.groupEnd();

    this.classList.remove("someClass2");
 }

});

  someTag[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.groupCollapsed(' See Information regarding variable values for click');
    console.log(someTag[i]);
  console.log(i);
    console.log(this);
  console.groupEnd();
this.classList.toggle("done");
})
}
```

However with ES6, we have let keyword, which gives us block scoping and you can use variable i inside event handlers and not have to worry about managing the variable state.

https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/53x2LdyL/.

addEventListener() method registers the specified listener on the EventTarget (element) it's called on. so its called everytime any event gets fired.

Comment: Thank you @Vatsal. I read the console logs and saw the 0 and 1 in the console. That made it more clear.